# Javascript - arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

- I'm a total beginner in JS. Now trying to handle arrays
- question: why the code below doesn't work. The aim is to make a function that adding the variable to the arrays but the outcome is still undefined. I hot stucked.

  ```
  var b = [];
  var n = 1;

  function name() {
    b.push(n);
    console.log(b);
  }

  console.log(b);
  ```

Comment: How are you executing your code? Actually, it's not giving any `undefined` output

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `name()` function, then your code will work as expected

```js
var b = []; var n = 1;

function name() { b.push(n); console.log(b); };

name();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also create an [IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/), like so:

```js
(() => {
  var b = [], n = 1;
  b.push(n);
  console.log(b);;
})()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you written function `name` is declared but never used. Try to call the function like this `name()`

```js
var b = []; var n = 1;
function name() { 
  b.push(n); console.log(b); 
}
name();
```

[chrome developer tools example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NkOQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

Either make that function IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression) or call that function

IIFEes are generally used for reducing the pollution of global scope.

First way by calling the function explicitly:-

```js
   

var b = [];
var n = 1;

function name() {
  b.push(n);
  console.log(b);
}
name()
console.log(b);
```

Second way is using IIFE

```js
var b = [];
var n = 1;

(function name() {
  b.push(n);
  console.log(b);
})()
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function or if you want to execute the function without calling it you should use the `IIFE`(Immediately Invoked Function Expression) pattern;

```js
var b = [];
var n = 1;

(function name() {
  b.push(n);
  console.log("Inside the function: ",b);
})();

console.log("Outside the function: ",b);
```